# How do i navigate to my other page xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

So I just created a new project, my first one that is. And I added two buttons and I want to do something like this.. When I click one of the two buttons, I want a my new .axml window to show, and I want to be able to go back once I am done visiting that page.

This is what I have so far

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace FirstApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "FirstApp", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnIncrement).Click += incrementButtonClick;
            FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDecrement).Click += decrementButtonClick;

        }

        private void decrementButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void incrementButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I also have a second .axml file with a checkbox on it named ***SecondPage.axml*** and thats the one I want to get to check clicking one of the two buttons.
How do ia ccomplish this?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android_multiscreen/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Jason had said, you can refer to [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android_multiscreen/hello,android_multiscreen_quickstart/).

---

In Android, every page you have seen is called Activity.

> How do i navigate to my other page xamarin android

That means you want to contain multi Activities in your App. And [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) will help you to achieve navigation between Activities.

So

- create a Activity named `SecondActivity` in your project
- in its `OnCreate` method  add `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SecondPage);`
- in your `incrementButtonClick` method, use `Intent` to navigate:

  ```
  var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
  StartActivity(intent);
  ```